# With what methods can I repair my shield?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

I'm aware that I can repair my shield at the blacksmith in town, but are there any other methods I can use to repair my shield?

I'm interested in a method which allows me to repair my shield while I'm out and about.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only option that I'm aware of is using the **Revitalizing Potion** to repair your shield on the field.  You can get at the **Bazaar** from the potions lady.  Of course, you'll need an **Empty Bottle** to be able to purchase it.

Comment: You may want to infuse the Revitalizing Potion with bugs (the husband of the Potion lady), so the potion will be used automatically when your shield breaks. Otherwise it will be gone forever.